# Passing metadata with Azure Event Grid subscription?

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I've connected my blob storage account to Event Grid, via an Event Hub subscription, and can see the events from uploaded blobs.

But I was hoping to be able to pass some metadata with each received event, so I can relate the event back to a foreign key (customer identifier) without having to do extra work on each event.

Is this possible?  I couldn't see anything in the API docs regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Azure Event Grid event schema for Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage) there is no metadata properties in the Blob storage event data.

Note, there is only one specific case passing some metadata from the AEG Subscription to its subscriber such as a query string of the webhook event handler endpoint (e.g. HttpTrigger function).

Solution for your scenario is using an *EventGridTrigger* function (subscriber) with output binding to the Event Hub.

The following example shows a lightweight implementation of the event message mediator using the EventGridTrigger function:

```cs
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    [return: EventHub("%myEventHub%", Connection = "AzureEventHubConnectionString")]
    public  async Task<JObject> Run([EventGridTrigger]JObject ed, ILogger log)
    {
        // original event message
        log.LogInformation(ed.ToString());

        // place for event data enrichment
        var metadata = new { metadata = "ABCD", abcd = 12345 };

        // enrich data object
        ed["data"]["url"]?.Parent.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("subscription", JObject.FromObject(metadata)));

        // show after mediation
        log.LogWarning(ed.ToString());

        // forward to the Event Hub
        return await Task.FromResult(ed);
    }
```

and the log output from the Event Hub:

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks. Good to confirm this isn’t possible with the current blob triggers.  I’ll have to get creative with mapping the blob to the customer identifiers.